# How to group by after date add in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have data below.

```
id: 1, created_at: "2022-01-01 02:00:00"
id: 2, created_at: "2022-02-02 23:00:00",
...
```

I need to group by created_at ("%Y-%m") after shift DateTime by adding 2hours.
Therefore after shifting hours, the date must be changed.

```
id: 1, created_at: "2022-01-01 04:00:00"
id: 2, created_at: "2022-02-03 01:00:00",
...
```

I can add hours using date_add function. But I don't know how to group by "%Y-%m" using created_at added hours in one query. Could you help me this?

```
select *, date_add(created_at, interval 2 hour) cr from clients where created_at between "${fromUtc}" and "${toUtc} order by created_at
```

Comment: What is the result that you are trying to achieve with group by? Can you show some sample data with expected result. Note that your query does not include any aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
SELECT 
  *,
  DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) cr 
FROM
  clients 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN "${fromUtc}" 
  AND "${toUtc}" 
GROUP BY YEAR(cr), 
  MONTH(cr)  
  ORDER BY created_at
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is meant to be used when you have aggregate functions in the query. As the query above does not have any, one should not use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The question literally says "I need to GROUP BY"

Comment: A `GROUP BY` over "%Y-%m" when you select all columns (`*`) makes no sense. This is not how `GROUP BY` works.

Comment: @slaakso, I would not know the columns the OP wants, so just for reference I put an *. I am pretty sure he can work on that

Comment: if DD just replaces the `*` with the columns that (s)he wants, it will still result to an error. Why not modify the answer to be valid SQL.